# Emacs: Convert string with multiple manipulations

Tags: emacs

I know, ridiculous title. Here's what I need to do:

Take strings that look like this:

```
* [1.1 Training]()
* [1.1.1 Special Training by Category]()
  * [A. New Hire Orientation Program]()
```

And add `.md` suffix to each and place results in the parens, like this:

```
* [1.1 Training](training.md)
* [1.1.1 Special Training by Category](special_training_by_category.md)
  * [A. New Hire Orientation Program](new_hire_orientation_program.md)
```

I'm using Emacs and need a macro that will:

1. Search each string (line)
2. Copy everything after the chapter number, chapter letter, or period, and before the closing " ] "
3. Transform it to lower case, remove spaces and replace them with underscores
4. Add " .md " to the results
5. Paste results between the parens

I'm trying to learn regex and string manipulation, but this one seems pretty involved. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often you need to do this, you might want to write a command for it.  But it can be done with `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-%`) with regexp `\[\([[:alnum:].]+\) \([[:alnum:] ]+\)\]()` and replacement `[\1 \2](\,(replace-regexp-in-string " " "_" (downcase \2)).md)`.  Notice the `\,`: it allows you to use elisp to transform strings.

Links:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html

Comment: Where can I learn to read the answer you posted? I will copy and play with it this one time, but I'd like to decipher it and apply the logic elsewhere. ("Give a man a fish, you feed him once. Teach a man to fish, you feed him a lifetime"-type thing)

Comment: Added some links that should explain everything.

Comment: For enhanced fishing capabilities, read (and search!) the manual within Emacs: `C-h i g (elisp)Regular Expressions`. You may need to learn how to use the info reader: from the `*info*` buffer you can type `h` to start its tutorial, and `d` to return to the top level page (which has some useful notes at the top).